# JMenu Item not calling method until clicked else where

Tags: java

This is a very odd bug and a VERY large program but I will post the code where they interact with each other.

So I have a minesweeper game where a "cheat" function is implemented and it reveals all the mines on the board.

this is the method that calls it:

```
public void showBombTile(){

    for(int y = 0; y < m_columns ; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < m_rows ; x++){


            if(m_board.get(y).get(x).isMine()){

                m_board.get(y).remove(x);
                m_board.get(y).add(x, new Mine(true,true,false,
                        "images/mine.png"));

                for(int i = 0; i < m_board.size(); i++){
                    for(int j = 0; j < m_board.size(); j++){
                        if(m_board.get(i).get(j).isMine() && i != x && j != y){


                            m_board.get(i).remove(j);
                            m_board.get(i).add(j, new Mine(true,true,false,
                                    "images/mine.png"));

                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

This method gets called via this method:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

    if(event.getSource()== m_revealBomb){
        m_board.showBombTile();
    }
}
```

and its creation and handler adder is here:

```
    m_revealBomb = new JMenuItem("Reveal Bombs");
    m_revealBomb.addActionListener(this);
```

its works EXACTLY as planned just when I click the m_revealBomb JMenuItem I also then have to click on a tile of the board and THEN it shows it. I assumed its nothing to do with the board but me nor 6 others can figure out this issue.

Any help is great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is made with Swing, try calling `repaint()` on the applications frame inside the `actionPerformed()` method:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

    if(event.getSource()== m_revealBomb){
        m_board.showBombTile();
        yourFrame.repaint();
    }
}
```

I'm assuming you repaint your frame on click, which is why why it shows the desired game state after clicking the board.